# Should I use 正解 or 当たり to mean correct in a testing situation?

Tags: words, usage, expressions

I want to use the term(s) when indicating a correct answer to a TEST question. I am thinking that one term may be preferred in TESTING situations, over the other.

Comment: Could you provide concrete examples of your usage of each of 正解 and 当たり?

Comment: I receive these terms as a response to my kanji submissions and give the same responses if the term is correct. I was just wondering which term is more correct to use when acknowledging a term is right.

Comment: I unfortunately have no strong sense of what a 'kanji submission' is generally, nor do I know if what I think one is accords with what you take one to be. A concrete example -- i.e. where you lay out an example of a chat you had, and you used these terms -- would be helpful.

You also ask "am I using the terms correctly?". But, what are your usages and proposed understanding of each term? How do you think they differ? These are all things that would be helpful in creating a clear, understandable question, which can have a clear, targeted answer.

Comment: FWIW, 正解 can be used in a variety of contexts.

Comment: Which term would be used in TESTING situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a Sino-Japanese compound, 正解 is more formal, and this is the word used in serious examinations and serious quiz shows. 当たり is more casual and colloquial, and it's mainly used for a riddle, a quick quiz, a "guess what" type question, or such.

当たり also refers to a completely random "win" or "hit" as in roulette or lootboxes. In this case, 当たり is not interchangeable with 正解.